# mysql query left join + count

Tags: mysql

I want a set of data from Order files that give me
CustomerNumber, Order Number, Product, Quantity, Price in addition to number of rows in order detail file for each order.
I am having trouble with the last part.

```
Select Header.CustNo, Header.OrderNumber, Detail.SKU, 
   Detail.Quantity, Detail.Price, Count(Detail2) from Header
   left join Detail on (Header.OrderNumber= Detail.OrderNumber )
   left join Detail as Detail2 on (Header.OrderNumber= Detail2.OrderNumber )
```

Comment: there is a missing comma here : Detail.Price Count(Detail2)
Also I don't get why you do twice the same join.

Comment: second time I want to do a count on detail lines, but this is clearly not the syntax.  I am reading up on subselects but my head she is hurting

Comment: You're missing a group-by clause. You're got multiple fields that are NOT being aggregated, and mysql will not know how to arrange things to do the count().

Comment: I want to group on order number.. in a subselect or WITH clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean? :

```
SELECT Header.CustNo,
       Header.OrderNumber,
       Detail.SKU, 
       Detail.Quantity,
       Detail.Price,
       ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM Detail AS Detail2
          WHERE Detail2.OrderNumber = Header.OrderNumber
       )
  FROM Header
  LEFT
  JOIN Detail
    ON Header.OrderNumber = Detail.OrderNumber
;
```

Comment: dont't need a GROUP BY in subselect?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge: No, because you only want it to return a single row. (Notice that it's a *correlated* subquery: it refers to the `Header.OrderNumber` from the outer query.)

Comment: bonzai! it works!! much simpler than what I was working on with temporary tables..